# "Note that for the x systems, we .." vs "Note that for the x systems we .."

Tags: sentence-construction, commas, sentence-choice

> For the x systems, we usually have harder constraints, such as ...
>
> Note that for the x systems, we usually have harder constraints, such as ...
>   Note that for the x systems we usually have harder constraints, such as ...

I suppose that the first comma is needed in the first sentence (?).
As for the second sentence, I am a bit confused. should I still use the (first) comma or not ?

Comment: I wouldn't place a comma. There's no need for it.

Comment: @SovereignSun Could you please tell me why ?

Comment: Commas are largely a matter of style and taste ([although there are a few places where you absolutely need them](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/607/)).  In this case no comma is needed.  Neither part of the sentence is an independent clause, it's not a list of items or adjectives, it's not a free modifier, it's not a quotation.

Comment: @stangdon Let us suppose that I want to use a comma. Could you please tell me if the following usage is correct: "Note that for the x systems, we usually have harder constraints, such as..", or I am obliged to use two commas, i.e.  "Note that, for the x systems, we usually have harder constraints, such as..", ? Thank you!

Comment: @tam - All of the extra commas are unnecessary.  You don't need *any* commas there.

Comment: @stangdon I thought that I have the choice to put or not a comma. So I just wanted to know if in the former case my comma usage is correct.

Comment: "Note that for the x systems" is not a sentence unit that could be moved elsewhere in the sentence as a whole (unlike "for the x systems"), so I think it is better to put in both commas, rather than one. Having said that, I don't know of any rules existing for this case and only using one comma doesn't change the meaning, so no, I don't think you are "obliged" to use 2 commas.

Comment: @tam, I've edited my answer to give more explanation, I hope it helps :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To paraphrase, the use of commas in your case is a matter of style, not grammar. Use commas (or not) if you want to.

AFAIK there is not a hard and fast rule forcing you to use commas in either case as "for the x systems" is not a subclause, but is instead an adjunct. Adding or removing commas does not change the meaning in either case, which would be the only thing forcing you to use commas (or not). If you are interested, [this article](http://uk.businessinsider.com/a-guide-to-proper-comma-use-2013-9?r=US&IR=T) has a nice list of "proper" comma usage, and [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/11016/51806) gives a very good explanation of adjunct use and commas.

As "we usually have harder constraints" and "note that we usually have harder constraints" could both be sentences on their own, and "for the x systems" can either go before or after "we usually have harder constraints" (because it is an adjunct), you can use commas if you want to.

The use of commas may help to add emphasis if necessary. Phrasing it like so:

> Note that, for the x systems, we usually have harder constraints, such as ...

emphasises that you are talking specifically about "the x systems". This makes the sentence sound cumbersome though, because of the abundance of commas.

It may be better to move "for the x systems" later in the sentence so you don't need to worry about it:

> Note that we usually have harder constraints for the x systems, such as ...